# Fix bottom bar in the listview which is inflated in new activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an application in which on clicking contact button from mail activity new activity is started which displays a list of contacts.Now i want to set a bottom bar in listview containg buttons.
How can i achieve this???

Answer (score 2):

you should place a RelativeLayout in your xml under with the property android:layout_alignbelow =  
or
alignParentBottom = true

this should place your relative layout at the bottom of the screen or below your list.